# Why does TreeSet throw a ClassCastException?

Tags: java, exception, collections, set, treeset

I am trying to add two 'Employee' objects to a TreeSet:

```
Set<Employee> s = new TreeSet<Employee>();
s.add(new Employee(1001));
s.add(new Employee(1002));
```

But it throws a ClassCastException:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Employee cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:542)
    at java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:238)
    at MyClient.main(MyClient.java:9)
```

But if I add only one object to the TreeSet:

```
Set<Employee> s = new TreeSet<Employee>();
s.add(new Employee(1001));
```

Or if I use a HashSet instead:

```
Set<Employee> s = new HashSet<Employee>();
s.add(new Employee(1001));
s.add(new Employee(1002));
```

Then it is successful. Why does the exception happen and how do I fix it?

Comment: You need to trust that the error message is correct. `Employee cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable` is the problem.  When you have one element there is nothing to compare so it doesn't detect the problem.  HashSet doesn't use Comparable so it doesn't check it either.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Either `Employee` has to implement [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), or you need to [provide a comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet%28java.util.Comparator%29) when creating the [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).

This is spelled out in the documentation for [`SortedSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html):

> All elements inserted into a sorted set must implement the `Comparable` interface (or be accepted by the specified comparator). Furthermore, all such elements must be mutually comparable: `e1.compareTo(e2)` (or `comparator.compare(e1, e2)`) must not throw a `ClassCastException` for any elements `e1` and `e2` in the sorted set. Attempts to violate this restriction will cause the offending method or constructor invocation to throw a `ClassCastException`.

If you don't fulfil these requirements, the sorted set won't know how to compare its elements and won't be able to function.

Comment: Ok so either Employee must implement comparable or i need to create an external comparator am I right?

Comment: But in present case Employee class does not implements comparable and there is no External comparator. Every thing works fine when i ad one element. Problem starts when I add second element. Question is if the scenario you described is mandatory then why compiler compiles that program.

Comment: @FireFly: It's mandatory, but is not enforced until the set actually needs to compare elements (which happens when you try to add the second element).

Comment: @FireFly: Without the external comparator, the class assumes the specialization parameter to implement Comparable interface. Either one must exist, but the compiler can't force such a constraint because it's not possible to do so at compile time.

Comment: @NPE Thanks for the answer explanation. I was asked in an interview and i failed to answer.

Answer (score 3):

`TreeSet` requires elements to implement the `Comparable` interface if a custom `Comparator` is not set. `HashSet` uses the `equals`/`hashCode` contract instead.

You can add only one element into `TreeSet` which does not implement `Comparable` because it does not need to be compared with other elements.

Take a look at the `TreeMap.put(K key, V value)` source code and you'll clearly see the reasons behind all your questions (`TreeSet` is based on `TreeMap`, hence the source reference).

Answer (score 1):

From [TreeSet#add(E)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#add%28E%29) JavaDoc:

> **Throws**: ClassCastException - if the specified object cannot be
>   compared with the elements currently in this set

Basically what you need is to let `Employee` implement `Comparable` or provide a `Comparator` to the `TreeSet` object.

If you check `TreeMap` code you will see that if the comparator wasn't found within the `Map` object, it will try to cast the key (your `Employee` object) directly to `Comparator`:

```
...
Comparable<? super K> k = (Comparable<? super K>) key;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

So implement Comparable interface to Employee object as it`s needed when you are using TreeSet, because TreeSet wants to keep elements sorted.

Comment: Is implementation of comprable Interface mendatory?

Comment: @FireFly: No, it's not. You can provide a comparator. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`TreeSet` is an implementation of `SortedSet`. You can either let `Employee` implement the `Comparable` interface or provide an appropriate `Comparator` for your `TreeSet`:

```
Set<Employee> s = new TreeSet<Employee>(new EmployeeComparator());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//class Employee
    public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee>{
    int id;

    Employee(int id){
    this.id=id;
    }

    public int compareTo(Employee e){ //implementing abstract method.
    if(id>e.id){
    return 1;
    }
    return 0;
    }


//class TreeSet

    Set<Employee> emp =new TreeSet<Employee>();

    Employee eobj1 = new Employee(2);
    Employee eobj2 = new Employee(3);
    emp.add(eobj1);
    emp.add(eobj2);

    for (Student ss:emp) {
    System.out.println(ss.rollno);
    }
}
//output: 2
//        3
```

Comment: Employee eobj1 = new Employee(3);    Employee eobj2 = new Employee(2);        //o/p : 3 only