# HashSet and TreeSet in Java

Tags: java, collections

```
Set s = new HashSet();

boolean b[] = new boolean[5];
b[0] = s.add("a");
b[1] = s.add(new Integer(5));
b[2]= s.add("a");
b[3] = s.add(new Object());
b[4] = s.add("4");
for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++){
    System.out.println(b[i]);
}
```

This is giving me this output as expected : -

```
true
true
false
true
true
```

But when I am using Treeset

```
Set s = new TreeSet();
```

It is giving me this exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
at java.lang.Integer.compareTo(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TreeMap.put(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TreeSet.add(Unknown Source)
at com.sunil.questions.TreeSetExample.main(TreeSetExample.java:15)
```

I want to know why it is showing me this behavior.

Comment: what does `TreeSetExample.java` look like, on oh, around line 15?

Comment: On a side-note: you shouldn't be using non-generic versions of a `Collection`. You might end up with a lot of weird problems...

Comment: @mcalex its the name of the class.

Comment: Duplicate of: [Why does TreeSet throws ClassCastException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943031/why-does-treeset-throws-classcastexception)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `TreeSet` is  sorted, it cannot sort `String` and `Integer` together.
  Thats why you are getting this exception.

If you just add the same type of elements, then you will not get exception.

This is where the generics come into picture, if you want your collections to be type safe, then you can declare them as `Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>()` or `Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>();`

Using this method, compiler itself will stop you from adding integers to `Set<String>` and likewise.

Comment: @Java_Alert Why do you want different objects in one set anyways?

Comment: @UlfGitschthaler,maybe out of curiosity :)

Comment: @Prasad kharkar : Means we can put only same type of elements in TreeSet.Is it?

Comment: @Java_Alert, As I said, `TreeSet` is a sorted collection. For a collection to be sorted, there must be some comparison thats why compareTo method gets called. If objects are to be compared, they must of same type. Hence TreeSet elements should have elements of same type

Comment: @Java_Alert It's not that simple. You can give the `TreeSet` a `Comparator` instance which handles whatever sorting you want, including your case with Integer and String.

Comment: @Java_Alert yes you can: `public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeSet<Object> objectSet = new TreeSet<Object>(new Comparator<Object>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                // add your weird sorting here....
                return 0;
            }
        });
        objectSet.add(1l);
        objectSet.add(true);
        objectSet.add("no");
    }`

Comment: @Java_Alert Although my previously posted code works, I'd really not recommend to mix different object types in one set, at least if there is a different way to achieve this

Comment: @UlfGitschthaler Yes sure I was only trying to know the reason.

Comment: @UlfGitschthaler, there is a way to achieve this using `Comparator`. You can create your own sort sequence with the help of it.

Answer (score 3):

**The root of evil here is not using generics**. You are instantiating a collection of unknown objects and expect Java to work correctly with them. Unfortunately, this time it can't - comparing `String` with `Integer` is not possible, at least not by default.

Use `Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>();` and `Set<String> s = new TreeSet<String>();`. The compiler will then tell you that you can't add Integer to a collection, you will be forced to convert the `Integer` to a `String` and all will work well.

Answer (score 2):

Use generics to instantiate your collections. You have a `HashSet`/`TreeSet` which contain `String` as well as `Integer`. This is not recommended. `TreeSet` is sorted so it will not be able sort with `String` and `Integer` as no implicit conversion happens. Use `Comparator` interface if you want to sort `String` and `Integer`.

Answer (score 1):

As we *know that TreeSet sort element while adding into it*. Here u are **adding string and integer at same time in TreeSet so u got error**. U can use different tree set for string and integer and then can merge.

Comment: You're not really bringing anything new to the table - why not post this as a comment to one of the answers instead?

Comment: Sorry i am not getting u what do want to say?

Comment: Look at the other answers - your answer is not really bringing anything new.