# Unhandled exception java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.TreeMap cannot be cast

Tags: java, collections, exception, treeset

I am trying to wrap a hashmap into another class, but I keep getting this

```
Unhandled exception java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.TreeMap cannot be cast
```

It is pretty simple, not sure why Java is complaining. Here's the wrapper:

```
public class ResponseHeader extends HashMap<String, String> {
}
```

and here is the cast

```
protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        // Save http headers
        mResponseHeaders = (ResponseHeader)response.headers;
```

the response.headers is defined as such:

```
public final Map<String, String> headers;
```

I looked into this thread, but it is not what I seek.

[Why does TreeSet throws ClassCastException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943031/why-does-treeset-throws-classcastexception)

any explanations? thank you!

added, I forgot

```
private ResponseHeader mResponseHeaders = new ResponseHeader();
```

Comment: And what is `mResponseHeaders`? You showed us `headers`.

Comment: I think your problem is trying to cast a `TreeMap` to a `HashMap`. To solve this, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19512912/1488669

Comment: sorry, I fixed the missing line but thank fanton. That worked:

mResponseHeaders.putAll(response.headers);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instance field `headers` is defined as

```
public final Map<String, String> headers;
```

You cannot make any further assumptions as to the type of `headers` than that it's a `Map`; the implementation of `NetworkResponse` is free to decide whatever implementation to use as long as it implements `java.util.Map` - it could use different implementations depending on the circumstances, or a different one in the next version of the library, etc.

But as you can see from the exception, in actual fact, at this moment, `NetworkResponse` is using `java.util.TreeMap` as the implementation for `headers`.

You're trying to cast it to `ResponseHeader`, which is a subclass of `HashMap` (but that doesn't matter, it wouldn't work even if `headers` was a `HashMap`, because you're trying to cast to `ResponseHeader`.

This is simply not the correct type of the object referenced by the instance field `headers`.  It is not clear from your question why you assume that it should be possible to cast `headers` to `ResponseHeaders`, but it's just not possible.

You're saying that you're trying to "wrap HashMap into another class". In actuality, you're extending `HashMap`, not wrapping it. If you extend a class, you create a new type, which is not equal to the type that you extended. Maybe you're trying to add functionality to `Map` that you would like. There are better ways to do that. (Wrapping is one of them)

Comment: I am not totally following your warn. I am extending the class, but do you think this can fail in the future, if the NetworkResponse changes?

mResponseHeaders.putAll(response.headers);